# How to hide app has stopped unexpectedly error window

Tags: android, window, xposed, xposed-framework

How can i hide the error window that says app has stopped etc..?
Or is there any xposed module that can do this?

Comment: I'm not getting your point. Error window occurs when your app crashes. Try to find the origin of the crash using Android Monitor Log.

Comment: im not looking for a fix. i just want the app to crash silently if an error occurs. how to hide the window? i dont want to get notified, it's annoying.

Comment: it's like the warning window that appears when increasing volume and crossing the limit. there's an xposed module which hides it

Comment: Um.... Learn what a try/catch is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do NOT recommend anyone do this, but you could put all of your code within a try block, and upon catching an error close the app.
For example:

```
try
{
    //all your code
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    finish();
}
```